# Is there a way to post Karate Cucumber Report to Slack without breaking formatting?

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, karate, cucumber-junit

To be clear, I have been able to post to Slack using the incoming webhook and sending a file link. However, I run into an issue where overview-features.html does not load with any of the supporting .css or .js

Below is what happens when I load my report from AWS s3. Yes I did upload the whole 'target' folder as well just to make sure.

[Cucumber Load Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0KgL.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really my area of expertise, but here is what I suggest.

Please start looking at the 1.0 series: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

We now have an HTML reporting engine that should make it easy for you to create a custom report if needed. You should be able to use the `Results` object and get all the data you need. I think embedding style information into a single "monolithic" HTML may be the solution.

But it does mean you should be willing to dig into the code and contribute where needed.